# How to transfer and save numbers

Tags: java, android

This code right here is a random math questionnaire and I want to know how to be able to transfer the amount of questions answered right and wrong to a separate stats page after each time they answer a question. I want the stats page to save the numbers so that if the user exits the program and then goes back on later they can still look at their total right answered questions and wrong answered questions. Ive been looking all over the internet and cant find a good way to learn this. If anyone has some advice I would really appreciate it. btw this is pretty much all the code in the main page; I didn't add the stats page code (because it has pretty much nothing.)

Pushme1-4 are the buttons and the AdditionEasyRight and AdditionEasyWrong are the number counts that are displayed on the main page.

```
public class AdditionEasy extends AppCompatActivity {

int countCNumAddE = 0;
int countWNumAddE = 0;
boolean hasAnswered;
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addition);

    final TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Count);
    final TextView count2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Count2);
    Button homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);

    super.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final TextView textTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final Button pushMe1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button pushMe2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button pushMe3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final Button pushMe4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    final Button begin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.begin);



    begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {




            hasAnswered = false;

            pushMe1.setEnabled(true);
            pushMe2.setEnabled(true);
            pushMe3.setEnabled(true);
            pushMe4.setEnabled(true);

            begin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            pushMe1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pushMe2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pushMe3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pushMe4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            pushMe1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            pushMe2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            pushMe3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            pushMe4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            pushMe1.setTextSize(20);
            pushMe2.setTextSize(20);
            pushMe3.setTextSize(20);
            pushMe4.setTextSize(20);

            textTwo.setText("");

            String randGenChoice1 = "";
            String randGenChoice2 = "";
            String randGenChoice3 = "";
            String randGenChoice4 = "";

            String randText2 = "";
            String randText3 = "";

            Random RandomNum = new Random();

            int randChoice1 = RandomNum.nextInt(40) + 1;
            int randChoice2 = RandomNum.nextInt(40) + 1;
            int randChoice3 = RandomNum.nextInt(40) + 1;
            int randChoice4 = RandomNum.nextInt(40) + 1;

            int rando2 = RandomNum.nextInt(20) + 1;
            int rando3 = RandomNum.nextInt(20) + 1;

            int pick = RandomNum.nextInt(4);

            randGenChoice1 = Integer.toString(randChoice1);
            randGenChoice2 = Integer.toString(randChoice2);
            randGenChoice3 = Integer.toString(randChoice3);
            randGenChoice4 = Integer.toString(randChoice4);

            randText2 = Integer.toString(rando2);
            randText3 = Integer.toString(rando3);

            int value1;
            int value2;
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(randText2);
            value2 = Integer.parseInt(randText3);
            final int value = value1 + value2;

            String line = randText2 + " + " + randText3;
            textOne.setText(line);

            final String answer;
            answer = Integer.toString(value);

            pushMe1.setText(randGenChoice1);
            pushMe2.setText(randGenChoice2);
            pushMe3.setText(randGenChoice3);
            pushMe4.setText(randGenChoice4);

            Button[] choice = {pushMe1, pushMe2, pushMe3, pushMe4};
            Button display = choice[pick];
            display.setText(answer);

            pushMe1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int buttonAnswer = Integer.parseInt(pushMe1.getText().toString());
                    if (buttonAnswer == value) {

                        begin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textTwo.setText("Correct!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        pushMe1.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyRight = Integer.toString(++countCNumAddE);
                            count.setText(AdditionEasyRight);
                            hasAnswered = true;

                        }

                        begin.setText("New Question");
                        begin.setTextSize(20);

                        pushMe2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        pushMe1.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe2.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe3.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe4.setEnabled(false);

                    }else{
                        textTwo.setText("Wrong!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        pushMe1.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyWrong = Integer.toString(++countWNumAddE);
                            count2.setText(AdditionEasyWrong);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        pushMe1.setEnabled(false);


                    }
                }


            });
            pushMe2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int buttonAnswer = Integer.parseInt(pushMe2.getText().toString());
                    if (buttonAnswer == value) {

                        begin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textTwo.setText("Correct!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        pushMe2.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyRight = Integer.toString(++countCNumAddE);
                            count.setText(AdditionEasyRight);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        begin.setText("New Question");
                        begin.setTextSize(20);

                        pushMe1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        pushMe1.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe2.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe3.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe4.setEnabled(false);

                    }else{
                        textTwo.setText("Wrong!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        pushMe2.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyWrong = Integer.toString(++countWNumAddE);
                            count2.setText(AdditionEasyWrong);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        pushMe2.setEnabled(false);


                    }


                }
            });
            pushMe3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int buttonAnswer = Integer.parseInt(pushMe3.getText().toString());
                    if (buttonAnswer == value) {

                        begin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textTwo.setText("Correct!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        pushMe3.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyRight = Integer.toString(++countCNumAddE);
                            count.setText(AdditionEasyRight);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        begin.setText("New Question");
                        begin.setTextSize(20);

                        pushMe1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        pushMe1.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe2.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe3.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe4.setEnabled(false);

                    }else{
                        textTwo.setText("Wrong!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        pushMe3.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyWrong = Integer.toString(++countWNumAddE);
                            count2.setText(AdditionEasyWrong);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        pushMe3.setEnabled(false);

                    }


                }
            });
            pushMe4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    int buttonAnswer = Integer.parseInt(pushMe4.getText().toString());
                    if (buttonAnswer == value) {

                        begin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textTwo.setText("Correct!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                        pushMe4.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyRight = Integer.toString(++countCNumAddE);
                            count.setText(AdditionEasyRight);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        begin.setText("New Question");
                        begin.setTextSize(20);

                        pushMe1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        pushMe3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        pushMe1.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe2.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe3.setEnabled(false);
                        pushMe4.setEnabled(false);

                    }else{
                        textTwo.setText("Wrong!");
                        textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        pushMe4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        pushMe4.setTextSize(30);

                        if (hasAnswered != true) {
                            String AdditionEasyWrong = Integer.toString(++countWNumAddE);
                            count2.setText(AdditionEasyWrong);
                            hasAnswered = true;
                        }

                        pushMe4.setEnabled(false);



                    }

                }
            });



        }
    });

    homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent homepage = new Intent(AdditionEasy.this , Menu.class);
            startActivity(homepage);

        }


    });

}
```

}

Comment: Use [sharedpreferences]( https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save and retrieve the values on the next page and when the user leaves your app

Comment: You could also  look at sqlite

Comment: Ive already read many sources on SQLite and sharedprefs but I don't really understand it all works and how to implement the sources into my code.